# Move CSS Grid content from one column to another

Tags: css, css-grid

I am learning CSS Grid and cannot figure out how to move the content from first column to the second column (concerning Desktop view +1200 Px).
I want to achieve some basic center alignment, just like with margin: 0 auto. Thats why I put 1fr before the 4 columns and 1fr after the 4 columns (grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(4, minmax(auto, 250px)) 1fr;).
But the content gets fit into the fist column - which is meant to center the 4 content columns.
I hope you understand what I mean. Please expand window to see the Desktop width.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/freshynek/d3bzLgvh/>.
```

Comment: Please add all relevant code in the question itself. Ping me when it's done and I'll reverse my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content is meant to go into the first column. You should remove that `1fr` from your template (it's a hack and will not work). Instead use  `justify-content: center;` to center `div.grid`.

Edit:
In theory you *could* add an empty div (`<div></div>`) before your first card. So the first column would be empty and the second column would contain your desired content. However as I said, this is a hack and if you're learning how to use grid you're better off not relying on hacks.

Comment: O.K. I edited the code according to your suggestion. Is this correct now?

    https://jsfiddle.net/freshynek/d3bzLgvh/5/.